# Rails 6 all validate_presence_of tests fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-6

they fail with: unitialized constant ActiveModel::SecurePassword::InstanceMethodsOnActivation

I'm trying to update a rails 5.2 app to the rails 6 beta, and everything seems to be working fine except for my validate_presence_of specs.

For example

```
RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
  context 'validations' do
    subject { Post.new(body: Faker::Movie.quote)}
    it { should validate_presence_of :body }
    it { should validate_length_of(:body).is_at_most(5000).on(:create) }
  end
end
```

the validate_length_of passes fine, and the validate_presence of does not. Posts do belong to a user that inherits from a Clearance::User, but I'm not sure why the constant would vary on different tests for the same model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this work.

There's a Pull Request to shoulda_matchers here:

```
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/1169
```

Until the shoulda_matchers team merge it, use my version here:

```
https://github.com/morsedigital/shoulda-matchers
```

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'shoulda-matchers', groups: [:test], git: 'https://github.com/morsedigital/shoulda-matchers'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bug with shoulda-matchers.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/1167

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was quick fix:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb - add to bottom

class ActiveModel::SecurePassword::InstanceMethodsOnActivation; end;
```